# How to calculate working days for an intern using python function

Tags: python-3.x

Peter studies and lives in Barcelona. He will start an internship in Sabadell in the next year and unfortunately, he has to pay to travel for the train. The supervisor of his internship gave Peter a choice: Peter can decide for himself how many days he wants to follow the internship. Because Peter does not want to have any loan in the end of his studies, he wants to calculate how many days he can follow the internship without ending up with any debts.

Write function internship_days that calculates the amount of days Peter can travel back and forth given his income and the travel costs, rent and other expenses he has to pay every month (hint: remember that Peter needs to come back every day).

Please complete the definition of the function. Here is what you can assume about this function:

The input parameters 'income', 'travel_costs', 'rent' and 'other_expenses' are non-negative float values.
The function 'internship_days' must return a non-negative integer as its return value, reflecting the number of days Peter can afford traveling back and forth.
The returned value cannot be greater than 30 (maximum days in a month that Pieter can do the internship, for this assignment: each month contains 30 days).

from assignment import internship_days
internship_days(1000,12,300,100)

Comment: shouldn't you do your homework by yourself?

Comment: So basically you want us to solve you college assignment without you even trying anything?

Comment: The thing is, I need help on how to start so that I can have the ability to handle similar questions

Comment: Please rephrase the question so that it doesn't sound like you're giving us your homework assignment. Make the question less broad and more relevant to others who might stumble upon it one day.

Answer (score 0):

from assignment import internship_days
internship_days(1000,12,300,100)

def internship_days(income, traven_costs, rent, other_exp):
    travel_allocation = income-( rent+other_exp)
    days = travel_allocation/( travel_costs*2)
    return days